# Static and dynamic linking on gcc

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, gcc, linker

I use lib3ds and opengl on my project. To generate executable file from this project, I can't link these libraries.

I use to link lib3ds below command on g++ : `g++ -o exec object.o --static -l3ds`
I use to link opengl : `g++ -o exec object.o -lGL`

I want to link both libraries in same command. If I try `-lGL --static -l3ds`, compiler says that `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried placing -lGL at the end of your command?

Answer (score 4):

`-static` asks compiler to generate static binary, without any links to dynamic libraries at all. What you want to use are `-Bstatic` and `-Bdynamic` linker options:

```
g++ -o exec object.o -Wl,-Bstatic -l3ds -Wl,-Bdynamic -lGL
```

Comment: I didn't work for me. g++ -o exec object.o  -Bdynamic -lGL, -Bstatic -l3ds/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL,

Comment: You forgot `-Wl,`. Also, better use `-Wl,-Bdynamic` *after* static, or linker will try to use static libgcc, libc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/xxx/lib3ds.a -lGL is works!

Comment: Can you prehaps expand your answer to make it more explicit what command worked for you in the end? It's a bit vague at the moment.